# when delete document in another collection How to delete edge collection document together?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, referential-integrity

I am practicing arangodb in company.
When I want to express the following relation between the user and the user, I want to delete the data of the corresponding following relation when one user is deleted.

**user collection**

```
{
    "_key": "test4",
    "_id": "users/test4",
    "_rev": "_V8yGRra---"
  },
  {
    "_key": "test2",
    "_id": "users/test2",
    "_rev": "_V8whISG---"
  },
  {
    "_key": "test1",
    "_id": "users/test1",
    "_rev": "_V8whFQa---"
  },
  {
    "_key": "test3",
    "_id": "users/test3",
    "_rev": "_V8yoFWO---",
    "userKey": "test3"
  }
```

**follow collection[edge]**

```
{
    "_key": "48754",
    "_id": "follow/48754",
    "_from": "users/test1",
    "_to": "users/test2",
    "_rev": "_V8wh4Xe---"
  }
  {
    "_key": "57447",
    "_id": "follow/57447",
    "_from": "users/test2",
    "_to": "users/test3",
    "_rev": "_V8yHGQq---"
  }
```

Comment: Please add code or effort which you have tried so for?

Answer (score 1):

If used properly, the ArangoDB system ensures the integrity of named graphs (GRAPHs).

To delete a specific user (say "users/test4") and the corresponding edges in `follow` manually, an AQL query along the following lines should suffice to delete the edges:

```
for v,e IN 1..1 ANY "users/test4" follow
  REMOVE e IN follow
  COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO counter
  RETURN counter
```

Assuming "users/test4" is not referenced elsewhere, the node can then safely be deleted, e.g. by

```
 REMOVE "test4" in users
```

The important point here is that when manually deleting nodes, all the relevant `edge` collections must be identified and managed explicitly.

Comment: To add a bit of rewording to the last part: if you use a NAMED GRAPH explicitly, Arango will make sure that the appropriate edges get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a graph with your vertex and edge collection. Working with graphs you can use the REST API to remove a vertex. This way all edges pointing to this vertex and the vertex itself get removed.

You can find the documentation including an example under https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/graphs/named-graphs/#remove-a-vertex

It is also possible to achieve this with an AQL query, for example deleting test1 from the users collection:

```
LET keys = (
  FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY 'users/test1' GRAPH 'your-graph-name' RETURN e._key)
    LET r = (FOR key IN keys REMOVE key IN follow) REMOVE 'test1' IN users
```

A graph traversal is used to get `_key` attributes of all edges pointing to test1, then these edges are removed from the `follow` collection and test1 is removed from the `users` collection.

Comment: ArongoDB purports to ensure the integrity of every GRAPH, whichever interface is used.  So for a GRAPH, the required AQL is trivial. It's only for non-GRAPH graphs that the explicit removal of edges is required.